# Accessing local variables of one method in another method C++

Tags: c++, local-variables

Well, they say variables that are declared inside a function or a block are said to have local scope i.e. these variables can only be used within the function or block in which these are declared.

But, after running following program, I got strange result.

```
int* ptr = NULL;

void Func()
{
     int x = 10;
     ptr = &x;
}    


int main()
{
    Func();
    cout << *ptr << "\n";        // prints 10

    *ptr = 555;
    cout << *ptr << "\n";        // prints 555

    return 0;
}
```

I accessed the variable "x" (declared in Func()) in main(). I was able to read and write to this variable in main().
I ran the code on Visual Studio 2015.

What's going on?

Comment: One thing to note. Your pointer has the address of a temporary object after `Func()` is called.

Comment: _"What's going on?"_ Undefined behavior.